# Rings with finitely many finitely generated free modules, up to isomorphism

Tags: ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra, algebraic-k-theory

If $A = \mathrm{End}(V)$, where $V$ is an infinite-dimensional vector space over some field, then it's not hard to see that $A \cong A^2 \cong \dotsb$.  In particular, the map $\mathbb{Z} \to K_0(A)$ sending $n$ to $n[A]$ has image zero.

Is it possible for the image of this map to be $\mathbb{Z}/n$ for other $n$?  This would mean, for some $m$, that $A^m \cong A^{m+n}$, but that $A^{m'} \not\cong A^{m'+n'}$ for all $m'$ and all $n' < n$.

(Of course, it's a standard result that for $A$ commutative, $A^m \cong A^n$ means $m = n$, so $A$ is necessarily noncommutative here.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are very nice algebras called Leavitt algebras which furnish examples of non-IBN rings.

Given a non-IBN ring $R$, let $m$ be minimal such that $R^m\cong R^n$ for some $n>m$. Let $n$ also be minimal with respect to $m$. In this case $R$ is said to have "module type $(m,n)$.

[Leavitt's existence theorem](http://www.uccs.edu/~gabrams/documents/FinalversionUCSDTalk7March2011.pdf) guarantees that there exists a Leavitt algebra of type $(m,n)$ for any prescribed $m<n$. If the slideshow is too sparse, check out the third chapter [of this online book](http://webpersonal.uma.es/~MSILESM/Pub_BST_files/APS_Edts.pdf) where Gene outlines everything.

I think this seems to be an example of what you are looking for, as $m'<m$ implies that $R^{m'}\ncong R^n$ for any $n$.

Comment: Thanks, this is just what I was looking for!